# How to make python requests upload to file-upload form

Tags: python, file-upload, python-requests

Whats the right way of uploading a file through this upload-file form on the HTML page using the requests module? I've tried with the following code, but im not sure how to include the form into my Python code?

The HTTPDigestAuth login is working and i get 200 OK, from the remote site.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth


with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "http://192.168.1.1/updatesettings.html"
    r = s.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('admin', '123456'))
    if r.status_code == 200:
        fin = open('backupsettings.conf', 'rb')
        files = {'file': fin}
        s.post(url, files=files)
    else:
        print("Login failed")
```

The HTML form is as following

```
     <form method='post' ENCTYPE='multipart/form-data' action='uploadsettings.cgi' onSubmit='return isInProgress();'>
        <b>Tools -- Update Settings</b><br>
        <br>
        Update Broadband Router settings. You may update your router settings using your saved files.<br>
        <br>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
           <tr>
              <td>Settings File Name:&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td><input type='file' name='filename' size='15'></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
        <p align="center"><input type='submit' value='Update Settings'></p>     
     </form>
```

Right now i get "ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer". But it could be due to that I havent specified the right parameters and stuff, hence that login works fine if i exclude the POST stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Check the action parameter in the form and the url in the code, first one is ".cgi" and the other one is ".html", ensure your request header contains the right "enctype" as well. The error 104 is because the server misshandle a wrong request killing the connection.
Use this for debug the requests and see what is exactly sent to the server.

```
import logging
try:
    import http.client as http_client
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    import httplib as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True
```

Comment: Its a .html page I call and on that page it calls a cgi script.